# Study the convergence of $u$ such that $u_{n+2} = \frac{u_n u_{n+1}}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

**The exercise**

Let $s > 0$, study the convergence of $u \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}^\star}$ such that $u_1=1, u_2 = s$ and $u_{n+2} = \frac{u_n u_{n+1}}{n}$ for all $n \geq 1$.

**My try**

Clearly, $u$ is of the form $u_n = \frac{s^{q_n}}{p_n}$ where $p_1 = p_2 = 1$ and $p_{n+2} = np_{n+1}p_n$, and $q_1 = 0, q_2 = 1$ and $q_{n+2} = q_{n+1} + q_n$.

So $q$ is basically the Fibonacci sequence which is equivalent to a constant times $\left( \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} \right)^n$ when $n \to +\infty$. But I can't find a lot about $p$.

I could nevertheless show by induction that $p_n \geq (n-2)!$. So, I thought a little about the convergence of $v_n = \frac{s^{a^n}}{n!}$ where $a = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} > 1$, maybe it could give me an idea. The non-obvious case is when $s > 1$ (by the way when $s \leq 1$, $u$ converges to $0$).

So, when $s > 1$, one has $v_n \to +\infty$. So, that is what I would like to show here for $u$.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: I get $\displaystyle u_n = \frac{s^{F_{n-1}}}{\prod\limits_{k=2}^{n-2} k^{F_{n-1-k}}}$. Since for large $n$, $\frac{F_{n-1}}{F_{n-1-k}} \sim \phi^k$, I think  $u_n$ diverges when $s > \prod\limits_{k=2}^\infty \sqrt[\phi^k]{k} \approx 3.2$